# How to get values from Post Method

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a form which as a input field (List). I would like to access that field individually. My code is below with output what i get.

```
 def alltestdata(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
      username = request.POST
      print(username)
  return redirect('lab:Dashboard')
```

My output will come something like this

```
         <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken':      ['vPkRRW9dCFLRRmVAm3PlOS1MURkZ6pSLBxz6ryEuVkwzuD2vW6mlWstFYxF2T4Tx'], 'name': ['gg', 'rr', 'rr','ee']}>
```

Comment: request.POST.get("name")

Comment: I have already tried it, in that case am getting only the last value

Comment: @CliftonAvilD'Souza: if you want the list of values, use `request.POST.getlist('name')`.

Answer (score 3):

The `request.POST` is a `QueryDict` containing **all** the elements that have been posted.

If you want the *list* of all elements attached to a specific key, you can use the [**`QueryDict.getlist`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist):

```
request.POST.getlist('name')  # => ['gg', 'rr', 'rr','ee']
```

Or if you are interested in the *last* element that is attached to a given key, you can use indexing, or [**`QueryDict.get()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.get):

```
request.POST['name']  # => 'ee'
request.POST.get('name')  # => 'ee'
```

The difference is that the former will raise an exception if no such key exists, whereas the latter will return `None`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if request.method == 'POST':
  username = request.POST.get('username','')
  print(username)
```

this will get username from post body if present else blank string